# How to output gridgain/ignite statistics to a file

Tags: gridgain, ignite

How can i capture operation statistics such as puts/sec, gets/sec per server  from ignite/gridgain.

Is it possible to output them into some file so that we can analyze them later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache stats for a particular server node can be acquired with `IgniteCache.metrics(ClusterGroup grp)` method, like this:

```
ClusterGroup grp = ignite.cluster().forNodeId(SERVER_NODE_ID);

CacheMetrics metrics = cache.metrics(grp);

long puts = metrics.getCachePuts();
long gets = metrics.getCacheGets();
```

You can periodically get them, calculate throughput values for this period of time (you will have to save the previous snapshot) and log to a file.

Note that metrics are disabled by default for performance reasons. To enable them set `statisticsEnabled` flag on `CacheConfiguration` to `true`:

```
cacheCfg.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a few questions about ignite metrics - 1. I have enabled cache metrics but I still see the cache puts as 0 for remote nodes (cache.metrics(ignite.cluster().forRemotes().getCachePuts()) while I have inserted 10k records in the cache. The local metric count is 210. What could be the reason? 

2. How do I get the count of cache entries on each of the nodes in the cluster?